# Does windows 8 support Visual Source Safe?

Tags: windows-8, visual-sourcesafe

Does windows 8 supports visual source safe (or the other way around?)

Aka, can you install visual source safe running windows 8?

Comment: Version of SourceSafe is important. I'm trying to install version 6 on Windows 8.1 and it's failing miserably. The installation begins, I put in my key etc. but when it gets to the actual installer, it freezes for a couple minutes and then tells me "There is insufficient memory or disk space to run Setup. The Setup program requires about 2000kb of free disk space." In fact, I have 16GB RAM and a 500GB hard disk barely used. Also tried running as administrator and in compatibility mode.

Comment: On the other hand, that was installing using the CD. But, I found this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/76953699-d0e6-40eb-b50b-83b12983ce37/installing-visual-source-safe-60-client which worked like a charm! It even automagically connected me to the server with my credentials and everything.

Comment: @JerryDodge there no longer is any reason to use VSS. GIT or Subversion will make life much easier (and faster)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is, don't go closer to Visual SourceSafe than you can spit a rat.  VSS has NEVER worked right. Data corruption is all too common. When I worked as an independent consultant to Microsoft in the late 1990's and spent some of my time in Redmond, I found out MS's little secret.  Virtually none of the Microsoft development projects used their own VSS.  Their internal source code control in the early '90s was a customized version of the old RCS file-based system.  They then bought source code rights to Perforce and created a customized version of Perforce for their own use.  Now, at least since Visual Studio 2012, they only officially support their own Microsoft Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) and Git.  Support for only those two has been built into VS 2012 and newer IDEs.

Again, even the Microsoft programmers joke about VSS being a "code destruction device."  If you already have a honking lot of projects in VSS 6 (which IIRC was built in 1998 and discontinued in 2006), you might want to track down the upgrade to VSS 2005, which is rare, but at least "supported" to whatever degree until sometime in 2017. I also have no idea if either is compatible with Windows 10 (I've installed 6.0 on Windows 7) I'm not sure it's any better, and Microsoft makes it very hard to find full or upgrade downloads of VSS 2005 on their site, but I recall seeing a link for it on one of the MS forums.  Search for it.

OTOH, if you are not welded to VSS and don't want to use either TFSC or Git, Subversion (standalone) is a very good alternative (CVS is a dead issue and is not being supported). My current client has development teams using either Git or SVN for their .NET (yuck) projects.

DISCLAIMER: My personal experience (as StackOverflow wants to see for opinion posts) covers 40 years as a top-level software design and development consultant for primarily Fortune 50 companies, during which I have used extensively just about every major COTS and open-source make utility, bug-tracker, and version-control system available.  I was a primary beta-tester for the original PVCS (Polytron Version Control System), later bought by Borland. I have also written a proprietary text delta-based version control system for Dow Jones in the early '90s.

Comment: I would not advice anyone to still use Visual SourceSafe. There are so many alternatives (Git,SVN) and I currently see using VSS as a ' code smell' of a company not to work for.

Comment: It is integrating well into Microsoft Access and very helpful there. I don't use it for versioning, but in order to keep my library modules in sync in my different apps.

Answer (score 2):

We've got it to work.

When it says you'll have to close all running program's it isn't just being nice.

Comment: How specifically did you get it to work?  What did you have to close?  I can't seem to get it to install, even if I boot into safe mode and close all running applications.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Install it when having all Visual Studio instances closed (just run it without any program's open). Install the VSS service pack 2 and reboot. That shoul do the trick. I'm running as an administrator, that might be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and in windows 10 too.
Copy and paste VSS from other computer in any folder in new computer.

For register in VB60 ide, execute SSINT.EXE
Find an run .EXE in VSS folder for other opcions

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It can be installed in Windows 10 computers too.